# How to set set-up angularjs testing with Karma and karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor in visual studio 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, jasmine, karma-runner

I have really struggled setting up angularjs testing in visual studio. As i have just battled with this for a few hours i thought i would share what i have found.

My aim was to have the directive and controller tests from the angular website passing (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) passing. The only exception being that the directive use templateUrl instead of template.

Directive:

```
app.directive('aGreatEye', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'ng-views/temp.html'
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<h1>lidless, wreathed in flame, {{1 + 1}} times</h1>
```

I had installed node and karma and set-up my projects as per this tutorial
http://codeforcoffee.org/setting-up-angular-js-jasmine-and-karma-in-visual-studio/

The problem i faced was getting the preprocessor working. I'm not sure of the issues i actually faced but i think it came down to the following problems
* the preprocessor module not loading
* the templates not being referenced correctly

Answer (score 0):

I installed karma, karma-jasmine, karma-chrome-launcher and karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor using npm. npm was run in the solution folder.

```
npm init
npm install karma --save-dev
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor --save-dev
```

I also added this configuration to karma.conf.js where WebApplication1 is the name of my application project

```
files: [
      'WebApplication1/Scripts/Angular/angular.js',
      'WebApplication1/Scripts/Angular/angular-ui-router.js',
      'WebApplication1/Scripts/Angular/angular-mocks.js',

      'WebApplication1/ng-scripts/*.js',

      'WebApplication1.Tests/ng-tests/*.js',

      'WebApplication1/ng-views/*.html',
    ],
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: { stripPrefix: 'WebApplication1/', },
preprocessors: {'WebApplication1/ng-views/*.html': ['ng-html2js']},
```

The need to strip the prefix to the template took me a while to figure out.

I hope this helps someone :)